# Converting Java ZonedDateTime to a different format ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, zoneddatetime

I have a java `ZonedDateTime` object in the following format

```
2017-01-16T21:03:10.712+09:00[Asia/Tokyo]
```

I want it to be displayed in the following format also as a `ZonedDateTime` object

```
16/01/2017 21:03
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Date objects don't have formats. You need to use a `DateTimeFormatter` to format them when you need to.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out more information at this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). You need to use a [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) and provide a pattern to the printed version, like that:

```
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now();
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
System.out.println("Default: \t"+ zonedDateTime);
System.out.println("Formated: \t"+ zonedDateTime.format(formatter));
```

Output:

```
Default:    2017-01-16T23:35:28.410-02:00[America/Sao_Paulo]
Formated:   16/01/2017 23:35
```

Checkout it working: http://ideone.com/0zcMJ6